# Which are the default modifiers for fields and methods in a Java annotation?

Tags: java, annotations, access-modifiers

Which are the default modifiers for `x` and `m` in

```java
public @interface Anno {
    int m() default x;
    int x = 10;
}
```

?

I suppose that the code above is equivalent to:

```java
public @interface Anno {
    public int m() default x;
    public static final int x = 10;
}
```

where the modifiers `public` and `public static final` are redundant, but I didn't find an official explanation for this.

I was looking here:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/annotations.html
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/index.html
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaAnnotations/article.html

Is there any documentation regarding those modifiers? Or could someone provide a "formal" explanation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, I believe you're right - and the one bit of documentation I've found to support this is in [JLS 9.6](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.6):

> Unless explicitly modified herein, all of the rules that apply to normal interface declarations apply to annotation type declarations.

So it's basically behaving like a normal interface, where `public` and `abstract` are redundant and all fields are implicitly static and final.

Comment: in a normal interface abstract is also implicit for methods.

Comment: @ratchetfreak: True - and it looks like that's the case here. Will edit when I get a chance - about to get off a train...